# How should I implement Nlog logger to reduce copy/paste tedium?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, nlog

I'm working on a .NET solution that will include `MVC` and `Web API` controllers. After admitting I deserved better than a roll-your-own logging solution and could benefit from some of the features in a logging framework, I selected `NLog`.

I've been looking around for advice on how to best add NLog to this solution. For starters, let's face it, placing `static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();` in every class is a bit repetitive.

So far, I found two solutions: my controllers inherit from a base class containing the aforementioned one line of code or implement an empty interface and use an extension method as mentioned [here](https://coderwall.com/p/hrm7fw/use-c-magic-to-turn-any-class-into-log-aware-class).

How can I make the logger available to all controllers (`MVC` and `Web API`) and what do current architectural practices say I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that [MS suggests exactly what you're trying to avoid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt694089.aspx):

```
public static class ApplicationLogging
{
    public static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory {get;} = new LoggerFactory();
    public static ILogger CreateLogger<T>() => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>();
}

public class Controller
{
    ILogger Logger { get; } = ApplicationLogging.CreateLogger<Controller>();
}
```

> The result, therefore, is an `ILogger` property **on each class** for which you wish to support logging

You can add such property by some kind of convention-based developing techniques, for example, create a [`PostSharp` aspect for a whole assembly](http://doc.postsharp.net/attribute-multicasting), which will find all needed classes in it and assign a logger for it. You may even create that property on fly with [`Reflection.Emit.PropertyBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.propertybuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are also some other solutions, but it dependents if this is on .NET Core or e.g. NET 4.5

> my controllers inherit from a base class containing the aforementioned one line

It's recommend that this will be a method and not a variable, otherwise the logger name is for all controllers the same.

> implement an empty interface and use an extension method

You could write the c# Extension on the `Controller` class. This won't work for ASP.NET Core as Controllers are POCO

Another option is to use [Anotar.NLog.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Anotar):

Their example is pretty self-describing:

Your code

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    void MyMethod()
    { 
        if (LogTo.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            LogTo.Debug("TheMessage");
        }
    }
}
```

What gets compiled

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyClass");

    void MyMethod()
    {
        if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            logger.Debug("Method: 'Void MyMethod()'. Line: ~12. TheMessage");
        }
    }
}
```

Fody is [not ready yet for .NET Core](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/206)

Personally I'm using a Resharper macro